# Figure out merged commit in prepare-commit-msg hook

Tags: git

I have tried creating a `prepare-commit-msg` hook that works for merge commits. The script gets passed the following arguments `.git/MERGE_MSG`, `merge`.

I need to get the hash or branch name of the merged commit (for a normal, non-octopus merge). I know I can do `git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD` to get the hash or `name-rev --name-only MERGE_HEAD` to get the branch name (if any).

However, it seems that `prepare-commit-msg` is called before MERGE_HEAD is created. Is there any other way of knowing which commit was merged short of parsing the auto-generated message?

I’m using git 2.4.0.

Comment: Have you looked into the contents of the file `.git/MERGE_MSG` (which holds the commit message so far) ?

Comment: Yes, it’s what I meant by “parsing the auto-generated message”. It seems to be a rather hacky and fallible solution.

Comment: I don't know how hacky it is, but this hook's purpose is just to customize this file.

Comment: It’s fallible because the user might have a localized version of git that produces non-english variants of the sentence “Merge branch x into y” (which means I can’t pattern-match the branch names) so I need to go through every valid branch name (which is probably every word) in the auto-generated message and check if that branch actually exists and is not identical with HEAD. This might also yield some false positives.

Comment: One can get the branch name via `NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 
`, but I don't know if this exists during `prepare-commit-msg`. It should work for the `commit-msg` hook. Another one : `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.

Comment: Yes, that yields the name of the branch I’m on, not the name of the branch I’m merging into the current branch.

Comment: I see. Another try: The merged branch name may be in env var `GITHEAD_<sha>=<branchName>`. Get it with `gitHead=$(env | grep GITHEAD)` and cut out everything up to the last "=" sign by `merged="${gitHead##*=}"`.

Comment: @harrymc That worked. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a custom merge driver, the name of the
branch being merged into (destination) can be retrieved
with `git symbolic-ref HEAD`
and the name of the branch being merged in (source) from the
`GITHEAD_<SHA>` environment variable,

This is an example script fragment :

```
# retrieve merged branch name from an env var GITHEAD_<sha>=<branchName> 
# we cannot use a sym ref of MERGE_HEAD, as it doesn't yet exist 
gitHead=$(env | grep GITHEAD) # e.g. GITHEAD_<sha>=release/1.43 
# cut out everything up to the last "=" sign 
source="${gitHead##*=}"

# retrieve base branch name from a sym ref of HEAD 
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD) # e.g. refs/heads/master 
# cut out "refs/heads"
destination="${branch#refs/heads/}"

echo "Merging from $source into $destination"
```

Source : [How to retrieve branch names in a custom Git merge driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302644/how-to-retrieve-branch-names-in-a-custom-git-merge-driver).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer.

I’m pretty sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302644/how-to-retrieve-branch-names-in-a-custom-git-merge-driver is the canonical source for this. codedisqus.com is just some mirror ripping off stackoverflow content. But since you rejected my edit, I’m posting this as a comment.

Comment: I’d love to upvote your answer but I’m missing 2 rep points… Remind me to come back once I have them.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick to reject your modification. It's redone now. I also upvoted your post. Thanks and good luck.